# Bast way to store some data

Tags: blackberry

In my app I need to store some text and audio data, and then display or play it. What is the best way to do this? What methods should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BlackBerry Java SDK - Data Storage - Development Guide](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/) should help you.

If its audio I would definitely store it in the file system. either in phone storage or SD card.